# Jquery to animate class on div using timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Am trying to make a jackpot spin interface using html and css. I please how do i add new class name to html element when play button is clicked and redo the process for 5 times on each element?

[image]

Below is the code

```js
$('.play').click(function(event){
    var speed = 200; // speed - timeout
    var rotate = 5; //number of animation
    var jackpot = $('.jackpot');
    for (var i = 1; i < jackpot.length; i++) {
        $('.jack-'+i).nextAll().removeClass("active-spin");
        $('.jack-'+i).prevAll().removeClass("active-spin");
        $('.jack-'+i).addClass("active-spin");
    }
});
```

```css
.jackpot.active-spin{
    border: 1px solid blue;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<div class="jackpot jack-1">JK</div>
<div class="jackpot jack-2">JK</div>
<div class="jackpot jack-3">JK</div>
<div class="jackpot jack-4">JK</div>
<div class="jackpot jack-5">JK</div>
<div class="jackpot jack-6">JK</div>
</div>
   <button class="play">Try</button>
```

Comment: setInterval or setTimeout with a closure is likely useful - click the `<>` and create a [mcve]

Comment: add a complete code, your CSS also

Comment: @TemaniAfif my css for `active-spin` is just to change the background image and add border color

Comment: i know, and you need to add it. You question need to be complete and not only a part of it. It's good if we can see your code working.

Comment: @TemaniAfif i have updated my question

Comment: @PhilipJems check again and tell me if we can run  your code ? where is the CSS of `jackpot` ? where is the play button ? the image of trophy is relative path so no one can see it, etc,etc. It hard for people to help you if we are missing things that you consider trivial. Take time and make a **working** code so it easy for us to help you

Comment: @TemaniAfif please check my update is runable now

Comment: @PhilipJems check my answer and let me know if it's what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want something like this :

```js
var current = 1;
var num = 0;
var max = $('.jackpot').length+1;
var rotate = 5;
var speed = 200;

function change() {
  $('.jack-' + current).toggleClass("active-spin");
  current++;
  if (current == max) {
    current = 1;
    num++;
  }
  if (num != rotate) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      change()
    }, speed);
  } else {
    $('.jackpot').removeClass("active-spin");
    current=1;
    num=0;
  }
}

$('.play').click(function(event) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    change()
  }, speed);
});
```

```css
.jackpot {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  transition:0.5s;
}

.jackpot.active-spin {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="jackpot jack-1">JK</div>
  <div class="jackpot jack-2">JK</div>
  <div class="jackpot jack-3">JK</div>
  <div class="jackpot jack-4">JK</div>
  <div class="jackpot jack-5">JK</div>
  <div class="jackpot jack-6">JK</div>
</div>
<button class="play">Try</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

I added a new param measuring the animation length in milliseconds.

```js
$('.play').click(function(event) {
  var speed = 200; // speed - timeout
  var rotate = 5; //number of animation
  var dt = 1000; // aproximate duration of the animation
  var jackpot = $('.jackpot');
  for (var i = 1; i <= jackpot.length; i++) {
    var j = $('.jack-' + i);
    setTimeout((function(el) {
      return function() {
        $('.jackpot').removeClass("active-spin");
        el.addClass("active-spin");
      }
    })(j), (i - 1) * (dt + speed));
  }
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.jackpot').removeClass("active-spin");
  }, i * (dt + speed));
});
```

```css
  .jackpot {
  background: url('https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQPnPO5H2gZ-VbzQm4sM9FtUzixFHUuicVq6qsDQ1z3csh75H5ukw');
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 80px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
}

.jack-1 {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.jack-2 {
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
}

.jack-3 {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.jack-4 {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.jack-5 {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
}

.jack-6 {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.active-spin {
  background-image: url('http://bestanimations.com/Games/Awards/trophy-gold-animated-gif-3.gif') !important;
  background-size: contain;
}

.play {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="jackpot jack-1"></div>
  <div class="jackpot jack-2"></div>
  <div class="jackpot jack-3"></div>
  <div class="jackpot jack-4"></div>
  <div class="jackpot jack-5"></div>
  <div class="jackpot jack-6"></div>
</div>
<button class="play"> Play </button>
```

Comment: if you use snippet consider making a correct running code without error. Unless simply put a code.

Comment: @PhilipJems, try it now, please :)